# Is there any way to scroll to the selected UICollectionViewCell in a collection?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a `UICollectionView` in a modal view controller in my app. When the modal view is brought up, one of the collection's cells is set as selected based on certain data I pass into the modal view from my home view.

I need to programmatically scroll the selected collection cell into view once the modal view with the collection appears... but using `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` while the collection view is being populated (in `cellForItemAt`) doesn't seem to work.

So while I could easily just use the `indexPath` available to me in `cellForItemAt` to scroll to the selected cell while populating the collection, since that isn't possible, I can't figure out how to scroll to the currently selected collection cell after the collection is fully populated and presented.

I can't even use a heavy-handed approach like looping through all collection cells and checking which is selected manually, since it doesn't appear possible to loop through cells that aren't currently visible.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable on Top.

```
   private var didLayoutFlag: Bool = false
```

Just pass the index number (`indexNO`) in viewDidLayoutSubviews method. I am using horizontal scrolling.

```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            if self.colllecitonView != nil  {
                if !self.didLayoutFlag {
                    self.colllecitonView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNO, section:0), at:.right, animated: false)
                    self.didLayoutFlag = true
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but how does this help me identify the selected cell in the collection? As in, my problem isn't that I don't know where to put `scrollToItem()`, it's that I don't know how to identify the selected cell outside the scope of `cellForItemAt`, which is where the selection of a single specific cell takes place.